# MS Access 2010 record changing on tab and enter

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am helping a friend with this database and when I select a record with the drop down it pulls up the correct record but when I TAB or hit ENTER it goes to the next record.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the forms design view open the forms property sheet.  In the Other tab change the Cycle property from "All Records" to "Current Record"